# ERROR mapreduce.ContentWriter: XDMP-NOTXN: No transaction with identifier 1796851315598328505 MLCP

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I got an error while using mlcp. I use mlcp in my load balancer so i just have one ip and at the back is i have 8 nodes.

But if i just connect it to one node the ingestion is successful. 
Please help...

> Connect to mklogic-ed03 18/12/13 08:05:40 ERROR
>   mapreduce.ContentWriter: XDMP-NOTXN: No transaction with identifier
>   1796851315598328505

Comment: Hm is your load balancer configured to use sticky sessions? You could give this a try if it is not.